# Neper Software Installation

Tags: cmake

I am trying to install Neper-3.3.0 but am running into some issues.

The instructions say:

1. Create a build directory, for instance as a subdirectory of Neper’s src directory,
   `$ mkdir build`

   - I use **cd** to change the directory to src and then I type `mkdir build` and a folder called `build` appears inside the src folder
2. Run CMake from within the build directory, pointing to Neper’s src directory,
   `$ cd build`
   `$ cmake ..`

   - I then use cd again to change the directory to the build folder but I don't know where to go from there.
3. Build Neper,
   `$ make`
   Use option `-j` to use multithreaded compilation.
4. Install Neper on your system (as root),
   `$ make install`

Comment: Normally you run `make` and `make install` from the build directory too. Did the cmake step generate a 'Makefile' ? If so then you want to be in that folder yes. Is that your only issue: where to run `make` from?

Comment: As @Rup has said. You normally run `make` from the `build` directory. I don't follow your comment "I then use cd again ...", as you should still be in the `build` dirrectory.
Also do you have all the [Dependencies](http://neper.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) installed?

Comment: @Katie you actually haven't said what your issues are with compiling Neper.

Answer (score 0):

The build folder should be at the same level as the src folder (ie, you can see it with `ls`). So, go to the neper folder you downloaded then:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../src
make
```

The `neper` binary will be there. If you want to specify install path and so on, add standard cmake commands during the `cmake [options] ../src` step

Comment: [The reference manual](http://neper.sourceforge.net/docs/neper.pdf) does say that a build directory within the source tree is supported though, i.e. the quote in the question is correct.